# How to use Vogels for DynamoDB to query by latitude, longitude and a radius?

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb, vogels

I have a basic react application using Vogels for DynamoDB and a collection with `latitude` and `longitude` entries and I'm trying to do a radius search.

Any ideas?